# Shape Error while Fine Tuning MobileNet On A Custom Data Set

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I was following deeplizard to fine-tuning MobileNet. What I tried to do is to grab the output from the 5th to the last layer of the model and store it in this variable x. The output of the 5th to the last layer of the model has a shape of `global_average_pooling2d_3   (None, 1, 1, 1024)`. Then add an output dense layer with 10 units. However, when fitting the model, I got the following error. Could anyone please kindly offer me some guidance. Thanks a lot. My code looks like the following

```
mobile = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet()
mobile.summary()
x = mobile.layers[-5].output
output =layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=mobile.input, outputs=output)

for layer in model.layers[:-23]:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=train_batches,
            steps_per_epoch=len(train_batches),
            validation_data=valid_batches,
            validation_steps=len(valid_batches),
            epochs=30,
            verbose=2
)

ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, 1, 1, 10) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the base model as follows, it will initiate with the default argument. Among them, `include_top` is set as `True`.

```
mobile = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet()
```

And, that brings ([source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.7.0/keras/applications/mobilenet.py#261-L263)) the `GlobalAvg` with `keepdims=True`.

```
  if include_top:
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(keepdims=True)(x)
```

Now, based on your error, I assumed your true label shape and here you can do simply as follows

```
mobile = keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet()
x = mobile.layers[-5].output # shape=(None, 1, 1, 1024)
x = layers.Flatten()(x) # < --- Here shape=(None, 1024)

output =layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=mobile.input, outputs=output)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @M.Innat, i'm very new to dnn. i was suspecting that i should reshape the output of GlobalAveragePooling2D. but couldn't find out how. Your answer works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your guidance.